# In tkinter text widget, failed to type in Indian language, rendering shows?

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode, utf-8, indic

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("1000x1000")
app.title("Desktop Translation App")
label1 = tk.Label(app, text="Sentence to Translate")
label1.grid(row=1, column=0)
label2=tk.Label(app,text="Add Translation Here")
label2.grid(row=20,column=0)
entry2=Text(app,width=50 ,background='orange',font = "lucida 13")
entry2.place(x=100, y=115, height=50, width=800)
app.mainloop()
```

while typing Indian language text in text box, it shows question mark,please help to rectify the issue. so the program should render in Indian language.

**Question mark in textbox of tkinter:**
[image]

Comment: It might have to do with font? The font that you specified(`lucida`) may not support _"Indian Language"_. Hence the `?????????`

Comment: It works only for  google input tool (IME) and on MAC(latest OS). Failed to work on windows IME, tried with different devnagri/indic fonts

Comment: so the issue was the font? have u solved it?why dont you  try some custom fonts

Comment: no its is not resolved with different fonts.

Comment: have you triedcustom font

Comment: yes tried  customfont=tkFont.Font(family='SakalBharati',size=12), still same output " ????"

Comment: that is not how it works, tkinter doesnt identtify custom fonts like dat, ill add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly declare your source file encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

This must be either the first or second line in the file.

Secondly you need to ensure your editor is actually saving in that encoding

Comment: Tried # -*- coding: utf8 -*- but still ???? showing, In latest MAC without any encoding its showing indic charactes, but failed for windows.